# how to make a rectangle/square with curved edges in html?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [css/ html help in making rounded table like container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000669/css-html-help-in-making-rounded-table-like-container)
>   [What is the best way to create rounded corners using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css)

how to make a rectangle/square with curved edges in html?

Comment: Curved edges? Perhaps you mean rounded corners? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css

Answer (score 1):

use CSS border radius: http://border-radius.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS 3 property `border-radius`.

Vendor implementations:

- Gecko: `-moz-border-radius`
- WebKit: `-webkit-border-radius`

Please note:

- [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) is used for specifying content of the document.
- [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) is used for presentation of the document.

Comment: It's maybe worth specifying the various vendor-prefixed options, too. I'm not sure if they're still required, though... =/

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the rectangle/square on a canvas, then manually round the corners. This method only works for HTML5-compatible browsers (not IE8).

http://thinkvitamin.com/code/how-to-draw-with-html-5-canvas/

Answer (score 0):

Curved Lines in HTML5 canvas http://fjd1.com/canvas002.html